# Snowflake Javascript UDF creation via JDBC client is stripping curly braces from function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using the Java Snowflake JDBC Client (3.13.10) and jooq to create a Javascript UDF. The query string that is constructed and fed to the JDBC client via jooq includes the full JS function body.

For example this is from my debugger attached just before the query is executed. Query content:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "DB_EXAMPLE"."SCHEMA_EXAMPLE"."MATCH_SCORE"(sources varchar,basescore double precision) RETURNS double precision LANGUAGE javascript  AS
$$
function main(sources, basescore) {
    let score = 0 + basescore;
    if (sources.includes("something")) {
        score += 10;
    }
    if (sources.includes("else")) {
        score += 20;
    }
    return score;
}
return main(SOURCES, BASESCORE);

$$
```

However, on receipt, Snowflake seems to be stripping some of the curly braces / brackets and messing up the JS function definition.

I can't figure out what is causing these to be removed between the JDBC client executing the query and Snowflake receiving it.

This is what I see run in the Snowflake **History** area.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "DB_EXAMPLE"."SCHEMA_EXAMPLE"."MATCH_SCORE"(sources varchar,basescore double precision) RETURNS double precision LANGUAGE javascript  AS
$$
function main(sources, basescore) 
    let score = 0 + basescore;
    if (sources.includes("something")) {
        score += 10;
    
    if (sources.includes("else")) 
        score += 20;
    
    return score;
}
return main(SOURCES, BASESCORE);

$$
```

If you look carefully you'll see the opening curly brace for the `main` function is missing, as are closing braces from the `if` statements.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Can you share the Java with the JDBC call sending the create statement (and any relevant statement preparation, etc.)?

Comment: Snowflake only runs what it was asked to run. The issue seems more likely from the client side. Please share Java code details.

Comment: You're both right here, something in the Java wrapper that is executing the query input must be changing it. I'm not great on Java so I'll need some time to dig apart the wrapper tomorrow and look into it. Unfortunately the code is from another maven package so I'll need to either step through bytecode to figure it out or get access to the source. I'll update here when I have more information.

Comment: Use [**tracing=ALL**](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors#JDBC) in JDBC connection string and check the log file. It will probably show more information and allow you to understand what is happening.

Comment: Thanks @Sergiu. I've narrowed it down by stepping through with a colleague - this code is using jooq, and jooq seems to be doing keyword replacement when it finds the curly braces for the function definition. So this is not a snowflake issue. I'm going to edit the question and mention jooq in the body to make that clear once I have this fully figured out. Currently looking for a way of disabling the keyword replacement/rendering in jooq configuration as a work around.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being that the JS function definition was being passed through jOOQ.

jOOQ was finding curly braces / brackets in the function definition string and interpreting them as keywords. The resulting output string of the definition would then be the post-processed version that jOOQ came up with after incorrectly thinking braces were delimiting keywords.

**From jOOQ docs**:

> Keywords: Curly braces are also used to delimit keywords, which expose
> the behaviour specified in DSL.keyword(String) (e.g. upper-casing,
> lower-casing, etc.) . The following expression makes use of embedded
> keywords in a plain SQL template:

```
DSL.field("{current_timestamp}");
```

Reference: https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/SQL.html

The quick solution here was to run UDF creation queries directly off the Snowflake Client Connection rather than via the jOOQ context, which avoided jOOQ trying to process the queries.